# How to use WITH clause with UNION ALL in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

GOOD Day for you guys , i have a question regarding the with clause with union all the select statment in the procudre is working fine but when i'm trying to add condiotion to each with clause it giving this error ("Inappropriate into") the below is an example of what i'm trying to do :

```
    

-------------------------------------------SOO1

            WITH SS AS ((        SELECT  /) */
                        COUNT(ROWNUM) AS S001
                     FROM x.MSSE A
                    WHERE (SUCCESS_STATUS='F'
   

                        UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                          COUNT(ROWNUM) AS S001
                     FROM X.MSSE A
                    WHERE (SUCCESS_STATUS='N'
                    
                
       ),

S333 AS
(SELECT             /*+ INDEX (A MSSEADTD_SI02) */
                     COUNT(ROWNUM) AS S333_
                   FROM X.MSSE A
                    WHERE (SUCCESS_STATUS='M' )
                

                    union all

                    SELECT       /*+ INDEX (A MSSEORMD_SI03) */
                          COUNT(ROWNUM) AS S333_
                     FROM HHL7.MSSEORMD A
                    WHERE (SUCCESS_STATUS='A'
                    ),

LIS AS
 (SELECT  /*+ INDEX (A MSSEORUD_SI02) */
     COUNT(ROWNUM)AS LIS_
      FROM A.MSS A
       WHERE (SUCCESS_STATUS='D')

SELECT SUM(S001) INTO Value_A
FROM
(
    SELECT S001 FROM SS
)        

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(S333_) INTO VALUE_C  
FROM
(SELECT S333_ FROM S333)  
 
UNION ALL  

SELECT SUM(LIS_)INTO VALUE_D FROM
(SELECT LIS_ FROM LIS)



IF Value_A > 30000 THEN  
--DO THIS 
 
IF VALUE_C > 30000 THEN
--DO THAT 
--...ETC
```

Comment: A union will return multiple rows; it looks like you want a single select that returns a single row with multiple columns, which you can then select into several variables. It's a bit unclear though - a [mre] could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equivalent to just:

```
  SELECT set_a.S001, set_c.S333_, set_d.LIS_
    INTO Value_A, VALUE_C, VALUE_D
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS S001
            FROM x.MSSE
           WHERE SUCCESS_STATUS IN ('N','F')) set_a
       , (SELECT COUNT(1) AS S333_ 
            FROM X.MSSE
           WHERE SUCCESS_STATUS IN ('M','A')) set_c
       , (SELECT COUNT(1) AS LIS_
            FROM A.MSS A
           WHERE SUCCESS_STATUS = 'D') set_d;
            
  IF Value_A > 30000 THEN  
  --DO THIS 
  END IF;
  IF VALUE_C > 30000 THEN
  --DO THAT
  END IF;
```

There is 0 need of those unions.

EDIT: If you have different tables you can adopt either of these methods:

```
/* Preserve unions and use it as subquery*/
SELECT SUM(S333_)
  INTO VALUE_C
  FROM (SELECT /*+ INDEX (A MSSEADTD_SI02) */
               COUNT(ROWNUM) AS S333_
          FROM X.MSSE A
         WHERE SUCCESS_STATUS = 'M'                 
         UNION ALL
        SELECT /*+ INDEX (A MSSEORMD_SI03) */
               COUNT(ROWNUM)
          FROM HHL7.MSSEORMD A
         WHERE SUCCESS_STATUS = 'A')

/* Use scalar subquery */
SELECT (SELECT /*+ INDEX (A MSSEADTD_SI02) */
               COUNT(ROWNUM) AS S333_
          FROM X.MSSE A
         WHERE SUCCESS_STATUS = 'M')
     + (SELECT /*+ INDEX (A MSSEORMD_SI03) */
               COUNT(ROWNUM)
          FROM HHL7.MSSEORMD A
         WHERE SUCCESS_STATUS = 'A')
  INTO VALUE_C
  FROM dual
```

Comment: Hello , you mean to say that i delete the whole Query and do the same as you did ? if so i have union all inside the s001 + s333 + LIS each one of them has multiple tables not just one @Gnqz

Comment: In your example the unions differ in just the success status and this could easily be replaced with an `in` clause. If the selects are from multiple tables, you can just either list the tables, give them alias and add the sums or use a union if you think it's more readable this way. If you provide the full select I can give better feedback.

Comment: i will just add more clear example now

Comment: Hi , please read my below better explanation

Comment: Added an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, it is `UNION` - but somewhat different from the one you wrote because part of data comes from one table (`x.msse`) and another from `hh17.msseormd`. It is unclear whether you can (or can not) join these two tables so ... `union` can be one option.

As number and datatype of columns returned by `select` statements in `union` must match, the 2nd `select` selects two `0` constant values.

The final `select` sums values returned in the CTE.

```
with temp as
   (-- values from X.MSSE table
    select 
      sum(case when success_status in ('F', 'N') then 1 else 0 end) s001,
      sum(case when success_status in ('M')      then 1 else 0 end) s333,
      sum(case when success_status in ('D')      then 1 else 0 end) lis
    from x.msse
    union all
    -- values from HH17.MSSEORMD table
    select 
      0 s001,
      sum(case when success_status in ('A')      then 1 else 0 end)  s333,
      0 lis
    from hhl7.msseormd
   )
select sum(s001), sum(s333), sum(lis)
  into value_a, value_c, value_d
from temp;
```

`IF`s follow, but - that's easier part, once you fetch `value_a` etc.

---

**[EDIT, based on your comment]**

If that's the case, then one "huge" CTE won't help at all. I'd suggest you to split it into several parts, one CTE per target variable. Something like this:

```
-- values that make VALUE_A: ------------------------

with ss as 
  (select count(*) cnt from msse where success_status in ('F', 'N') 
   union all
   select count(*) cnt from abcd where xyz = 23
   union all
   ...
  )
select sum(cnt)
  into value_a
  from ss;
  
-- values that make VALUE_C: ------------------------

with s333 as 
  (select count(*) cnt from msse where success_status in ('M') 
   union all
   select count(*) cnt from msseormd where success_status = 'A'
   union all
   select count(*) cnt from qwerty where zzy = 154
   union all 
   ...
  )
select sum(cnt)
  into value_c
  from s333;

-- etc., for all VALUE_x variables
```

---

As of error you got: you can't have multiple `INTO` clauses in the same `SELECT` statement. You could, though, do this:

```
with (your current CTE goes here)
-- final SELECT:
select (select sum(s001_) from ss),
       (select sum(s333_) from s333),
       (select sum(lis_)  from lis)
into value_a, value_c, value_d
from dual
```

but I'd say that - if there are dozens of tables involved, one huge CTE really doesn't help at all, but makes things more complex than they should be.

Comment: Hi , i will explain it better (S001 has more than 10 tables in it and more than just one condition  i want the sum of the values to be used it last by the IF , i was able to do the select statement for all the variables but when i got to use the IF its giving the error that i showed in title (("Inappropriate into) ) i was just trying to make my case simpler hence i cut a lot of tables and unions